# To find number of occurrences of a word taken as input from command line in unix

Tags: unix, command-line, grep

For the file `file1.txt` which contains

```
Apple fruit Apple tree
Tree AApple AApklle Apple apple
TREE
Apple
```

I want to find number of occurrences of the word `Apple`. Output should be `4`.
My script.sh file contains

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="$1"
TOFIND="$2"
if [ -f "$FILE" ];
then
grep -o '\<"$TOFIND"\>' "$FILE" | wc -l
fi
```

When I try using

```
bash script.sh file1.txt Apple
```

The output shows `0`. Please help solve this problem.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: ... or use `grep -wo "$TOFIND" "$FILE" | wc -l` with GNU grep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the grep line to:

```
grep -o '\<'"$TOFIND"'\>' "$FILE" | wc -l
```

or just:

```
grep -o "\<$TOFIND\>" "$FILE" | wc -l
```

Then it will work. It's because the quotes, your double quotes was quoted inside single quotes, so they are not expanded.

Answer (score 1):

One in awk:

```
$ awk -v w="Apple" 'BEGIN{RS="( |\n)+"}{c+=($1==w)}END{print c}' file
4
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -v w="Apple" '     # search word as parameter
BEGIN {
    RS="( |\n)+"         # set record separator to separate words
    # RS="[[:space:]]+"  # where available
}{
    c+=($1==w)           # count searched words
}
END {                    # in the end
   print c+0             # output count
}' file
```

`RS="( |\n)+"` is tested to work on gawk, mawk and Busybox awk, it failed to work on Debian's original-awk. `RS="[[:space:]]+"` tested to work on gawk only.

Comment: You should mention those are gawk-only for multi-char RS and you should print `c+0` to ensure a number is output for empty files rather than a null string.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='\\<Apple\\>' 'END{print (NR ? NR-1 : 0)}' file
4
```

or with a shell variable:

```
$ tofind='Apple'
$ awk -v RS='\\<'"$tofind"'\\>' 'END{print (NR ? NR-1 : 0)}' file
4
```