# How to count the occurrence of given words in files?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

#### Problem

This script checks for different words in different files. Without knowing the word earlier, how do I count its occurrence?

#### Output

The output should be numeric value, if it matches the searched word in a given file, else should reply with the invalid output.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "Hello" -ne 1 ] 
 then
  echo "Pass appropriate number of command line arguments"
else
 if [ -e "$1" ]
 then
      if [ -f "$1" ]
      then
            if [ -r "$1" ]
            then
                   grep -wc "Hello" $1
            else
                   echo "Input file does not have read permission"
            fi
      else
            echo "Input file is not an ordinary file"
      fi
 else
      echo "Input file does not exist"
  fi
fi
```

Comment: what's your question ?

Comment: There was one like this like 5 questions back: [To find number of occurrences of a word taken as input from command line in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54967583/to-find-number-of-occurrences-of-a-word-taken-as-input-from-command-line-in-unix/)

Comment: `if [ "Hello" -ne 1 ]` makes no sense. `"Hello"` will always be different from `1`, even worse `"Hello"` is not an integer and will therefore cause an error.

Answer (score 1):

To count a word in a file you can consider creating such a file

```
#!/bin/bash 
#search_word.sh
cnt=$(grep "$1" "$2" -o | wc -l)
if [ "$cnt" -eq 0 ] 
then
  echo "This file has no word as $1"
else
  echo "This file has $cnt times of the word $1"
fi
```

and invoke from the command prompt as

```
$ . ./search_word.sh 'myword' myfile.txt
```

- `wc` stand for `word count`
- if you want to count case-insensitively(e.g. `WORD` or `WorD` or
  `word` considered to be the same), then replace the flag `-o` before
  `| wc -l` with `-io`
- if you look for exact match for any word(e.g. `WOR` is not to be counted during the search for `Word` ), then replace the flag `-o` before
  `| wc -l` with `-wio`